# Switch between adding and deleting html based on dropdown box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to building a form that is used for creating other form. I fill out all the information and it creates a json string that is stored in a database.  I have my form built and I'm able to add multiple form fields dynamically. However, I'm wanting the fields options to change as I change the field type in a dropdown select box. For instance, if I select the field type "text", only the "required" checkbox will appear, but if I select the "select" type, the "required" checkbox will appear and the "options" textboxes will appear. Each different option is within their own div container. I don't want to just simply hide and show the divs based on the dropdown selection, because I don't want the empty textboxes or checkboxes to post when I submit the form.

I am very new to jQuery. Am I able to use html templates? and how if so? I hope this makes since. I would be happy to explain further.

'

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open(); ?>

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#general" aria-controls="general" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#fields" aria-controls="fields" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fields</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#after_submit" aria-controls="after_submit" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">After Submit</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">

            <div class="html-container"></div>

            <br>

            <!-- GENERAL FORM INFO TAB -->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="general">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $form->name), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="slug" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Slug:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('slug', set_value('slug', $form->slug), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="send_button_text" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Send Button Text:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('send_button_text', set_value('send_button_text', $form->send_button_text), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="save_entries" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Save Entries</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <?php echo form_radio('save_entries', 'yes', set_value('save_entries', $form->save_entries)); ?> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <?php echo form_radio('save_entries', 'no', set_value('save_entries', $form->save_entries)); ?> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="is_public" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Public</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <?php echo form_radio('is_public', 'yes', set_value('is_public', $form->is_public)); ?> Yes
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <?php echo form_radio('is_public', 'no', set_value('is_public', $form->is_public)); ?> No
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- //..end of 'general' tab panel -->

            <!-- INPUT FIELDS TAB -->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fields">

                <div class="repeat">

                    <div class="repeat-wrapper">

                        <div class="repeat-container">

                            <div class="repeat-template repeat-row">

                                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

                                    <div class="panel panel-default">

                                        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading{{row-count}}">

                                            <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">
                                                <span class="move"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{row-count}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{row-count}}">
                                                    Panel title
                                                </a>
                                            </h3>
                                            <?php echo form_button('remove_field_button', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remove', 'class="remove btn btn-link pull-right"'); ?>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                        </div>

                                        <div id="collapse{{row-count}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading{{row-count}}">
                                            <div class="panel-body">

                                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                                    <label for="inputs[{{row-count}}][name]" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                        <?php echo form_input('inputs[{{row-count}}][name]', '', 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                                    <label for="inputs[{{row-count}}][label]" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                                        <?php echo form_input('inputs[{{row-count}}][label]', '', 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                                    <label for="inputs[{{row-count}}][type]" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                        <?php echo form_dropdown('inputs[{{row-count}}][type]', $types, '', 'class="form-control input_type" data-counter="{{row-count}}"'); ?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div id="input_required_{{row-count}}" class="form-group input-type-show-hide">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
                                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                                            <label>
                                                                <?php echo form_checkbox('inputs[{{row-count}}][required]', 'yes', ''); ?>
                                                                <?php echo form_checkbox('inputs[{{row-count}}][required]', 'no', ''); ?> Required
                                                            </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                    <div id="input_options_{{row-count}}" class="row input-type-show-hide">

                                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                                                            <table class="table repeat-wrapper">

                                                                <thead>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th>Label</th>
                                                                        <th>Value</th>
                                                                        <th></th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </thead>

                                                                <tfoot>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="3">
                                                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                                                    <?php echo form_button('add_option_button', 'Add Option', 'class="add btn btn-link"'); ?>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>                                                              
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tfoot>

                                                                <tbody class="repeat-container">

                                                                    <tr class="form-inline repeat-template repeat-row">

                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                                                                <label for="inputs[{{row-count}}][options][{{row-count}}][label]" class="sr-only">Label</label>
                                                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                                                    <?php echo form_input('inputs[{{row-count}}][options][{{row-count}}][label]', '', 'class="form-control" placeholder="Label"'); ?>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                                                                <label for="inputs[{{row-count}}][options][{{row-count}}][value]" class="sr-only">Value</label>
                                                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                                                    <?php echo form_input('inputs[{{row-count}}][options][{{row-count}}][value]', '', 'class="form-control" placeholder="Value"'); ?>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span class="remove">Remove</span>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                    </tr> <!-- //..end of repeat-template for options -->

                                                                </tbody> <!-- //..end of repeat-container for options -->

                                                            </table> <!-- //..end of repeat-wrapper for options -->

                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>


                                                <div class="att_block_{{row-count}}"></div>

                                            </div> <!-- //..end of panel body -->

                                        </div> <!-- //..end of tabpanel -->

                                    </div> <!-- //..end of panel div -->

                                </div> <!-- //..end of panel group -->

                            </div> <!-- //..end of repeat-template -->

                        </div> <!-- //..end of repeat-container -->

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <?php echo form_button('add_field_button', 'Add Another', 'class="add btn btn-link"'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- //..end of 'add another' form-group -->

                    </div><!--  //..end of repeat-wrapper -->

                </div> <!-- //..end of repeat div -->

            </div> <!-- //..end of 'fields' tab panel -->

            <!-- AFTER SUBMIT TAB    -->
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="after_submit">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_recipients" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Recipients:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('email_recipients', set_value('email_recipients', $form->email_recipients), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_cc" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email CC:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('email_cc', set_value('email_cc', $form->email_cc), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_bcc" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email BCC:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('email_bcc', set_value('email_bcc', $form->email_bcc), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_subject" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('email_subject', set_value('email_subject', $form->email_subject), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email_message" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email Message:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?php echo form_textarea('email_message', set_value('email_message', $form->email_message), 'class="tinymce"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="after_submit_text" class="col-sm-3 control-label">After Submit Text:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <?php echo form_textarea('after_submit_text', set_value('after_submit_text', $form->after_submit_text), 'class="tinymce"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="return_url" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Return URL:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <?php echo form_input('return_url', set_value('return_url', $form->return_url), 'class="form-control"'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div> <!-- //..end of 'after_submit' tab panel -->

        </div>  <!-- //..end of tab-content  -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-5">
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-default"'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#myTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: ".tinymce",
    plugins: "code",
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist | code",
    menubar: false
});

$('.repeat').each(function() {
    $(this).repeatable_fields({
        wrapper: '.repeat-wrapper',
        container: '.repeat-container',
        row: '.repeat-row',
        template: '.repeat-template',
        row_count_placeholder: '{{row-count}}'
    });
});

template = $("#test_html").clone();

template.appendTo(".html-container");

//$( ".html-container" ).append( $( "#test_html" ) );

$("body").on("change", ".input_type", function () {



});

});
</script>'
```

Comment: sorry about that...i made the change...didn't even think about it

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `hide()` method to conceal parts of the DOM which you want to be submitted with the form and use `remove()` to take them completely out of the DOM, thereyby preventing their submission.

See the [jQuery remove method](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: ok cool..what if I want to start out by not displaying parts of the DOM and add them after the dropdown change? and is there a better way to toggle back and forth

Comment: If by "not displaying and add them after the dropdown change" you mean creating new elements, many jQuery methods exist for that, including `html()`, `append()`, `before`, `after`... If you want them loaded with the page but hidden, then CSS will do (`display:none`)